# Capturing a group in a pattern used in a Vim autocmd

Tags: vimscript, neovim, syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, autocmd

I need Vim to ignore the `.tmpl` file extension to enable syntax highlighting.

How can I rewrite this:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.lua.tmpl set filetype=lua
```

to be more general? I want to match the lua and use it in the filetype.

Something like this is what I want:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.\(.*\).tmpl set filetype=\1
```

I use Neovim and I am currently wrapping the above in `vim.cmd()`. If this is somehow easier to do with `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd`, then this is fine, too.

One way would be to copy and paste for each file extension.
Because I don't want to do that, I was going to make a chezmoi (dotfile manager) template that automatically finds all extensions that I need. I doubt that this will be good for performance, though. Also seems like a lot of work for something that sounds easy.

I tried to escape the pattern and somehow use `\v` magic but I am unable to.
I wasn't able to find an example so I came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like

```
" ~/.vim/ftdetect/tmpl.vim
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tmpl execute 'set filetype='..matchlist(expand('<afile>'), '.*\.\(.*\)\.tmpl$')[1]
```

Better error handling would be worthwhile, however.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
for ext in ['lua', 'tex']
  execute 'autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.' .. ext .. '.tmpl set filetype=' .. ext
endormi
```

But bear in mind that, in general, the file extension (e.g. `.py`) could be different than the `filetype` (e.g. `python`)

Comment: Remark the file pattern and the text pattern are different in Vim see `:help file-pattern`

Comment: This is what I settled on for now. But is there no way to capture any arbitrary `ext`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware off.

Comment: I'm assuming capital `EX` was a typo?

Comment: @Ben, thanks :-) I have updated the code.